# How can I fix characters not sitting on chairs properly?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

When sitting on chairs, is annoying see your char floating on air near it.

But with the Corvega mod it is difficult to play. I am forced to open console and type TCL to be able to push the light buttons of the car or access the gloves container.

What can be causing that bug?

PS.: This has been happening long time ago before using that mod. Just that I never really care about it, til now...

How it happens: after I click to sit on chair, my char looks like he is sat, but the chair is not below him... he always "sit" in the air near the chair, sometimes to the left, other times in front of it, but never above the chair. "To sit" is actually an animation, but the animation happens in the wrong place, so the camera (on the head of the char) is positioned wrongly too.

[image: floating instead of sitting on chair]

Comment: Could you explain a bit deeply about what's going on? do you have any screenshots to aid? It's difficult for us to tell what you are talking about.

Comment: after I click to sit on chair, my char looks like he is sat, but the chair is not below him... he always "sit" in the air near the chair, sometimes to the left, other times in front of it, but never above the chair. "To sit" is actually an animation, but the animation happens in the wrong place, so the camera (on the head of the char) is positioned wrongly too and I cannot see the interior of the car properly.. :(

Comment: Have  you tried starting a new game without any mods?